# Microsoft graph v/s azure ad graph api v/s office 365 api

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I have started exploring these technologies and gone through some documentations. But its hard to figure out the limitations, advantages and which is best in what scenario.

Can anyone tell me the differences, advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan Kershaw wrote an excellent [article comparing the Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).  It was updated in May 2017 to reflect new functionality we've brought to Microsoft Graph API.

> In general, we recommend the use of Microsoft Graph over Azure AD Graph, as Microsoft Graph is where we are investing for Microsoft cloud services.

The Microsoft Graph continues to see new features and has nearly closed the gap. Through the Microsoft Graph, you can access Office APIs (like calendar, mail, contacts, etc) and Azure AD APIs (organization hierarchy, users, etc.).  It's highly recommended that you use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) in your application but the Azure AD Graph API is still available if you need it.

Also, be sure to check out the [Microsoft Graph client libraries and code samples](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks) that are available in many languages.